# Android - access clipboard from non-UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I have an Android application which starts a background service (running in its own process) when a button is clicked. This service connects to a remote machine whose IP is specified in the UI.

This service starts a thread which creates the connection. If the connection is successful, two more threads are started (one to handle sending of and other to handle receiving of data).

One of these latter 2 threads (the sending one) is supposed to monitor the clipboard for changes and get the changed text for processing. For this, I have the following code in the thread's `run` method:

```
        final ClipboardManager clipBoard  = (ClipboardManager)appContext.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        if(clipBoard != null) {
            clipBoard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
                    if(clipBoard.hasPrimaryClip()) {
                        if(clipBoard.getPrimaryClipDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
                            ClipData.Item textItem = clipBoard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);
                            String text = textItem.getText().toString();

                            if(text != null) {
                                  //do something with the text
                            }
                        }
                    }
                 }
             });
        }
```

However, when running the application, I get the error:
`Can't create handler inside thread which has not called Looper.prepare()`.

I read about Loopers, but couldn't understand how that can be used in my case. What do I need to do to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Without more code it hard to tell exactly, but probably your problem is that `OnPrimaryClipChangedListener` use `Handler` in his implementation, and `Handler` must call `Looper.prepare()` by definition.